# Ansible DellOS6 Config Backup

Tags: ansible

EDIT: After some research, I wonder if this may be related to the on_become() function as described in this post? https://github.com/Dell-Networking/ansible-dellos-examples/issues/12

I am trying to backup our current configurations on our Dell 2048p switches, running OS6. No matter what I set the timeout to (using persistent_connection in ansible.cfg), it still errors out. I have checked the logs on the switch and it gets both the show ver and show running-config commands, however its just not making it back. I have looked at the Networking and Troubleshooting guide, but am having trouble getting a proper error. Does anyone have this working, or spot anything I can change?

Version

```
ansible 2.9.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/me/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) [GCC 8.3.0]
```

Playbook

```
-
  name: Show ver
  hosts: Dell
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - 
    name: "Get Dell EMC OS6 Show version"
    dellos6_command:
      commands: ['show version']
    register: show_ver
  -
    name: "Backup config file locally"
    dellos6_config:
      backup: yes
      backup_options:
        dir_path: "/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/Programming Projects/netBackupPlaybooks"
        filename: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      authorize: yes
    register: backup_dellso6_location
    when: ansible_network_os == 'dellos6'

  - debug: var=show_ver
  - debug: var=backup_dellos6_location
```

Inventory

```
[Dell]
sw1 ansible_host=10.10.10.10 ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible_network_os=dellos6 ansible_connection=network_cli ansible_become_method=enable ansible_become_password=admin ansible_user=admin ansible_password=admin 
sw2 ansible_host=10.10.10.11 ansible_ssh_extra_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' ansible_network_os=dellos6 ansible_connection=network_cli ansible_become_method=enable ansible_become_password=admin ansible_user=admin ansible_password=admin
```

Command

```
sudo ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini DellPB.yaml -vvvv
```

Error

```
The full traceback is:
WARNING: The below traceback may *not* be related to the actual failure.
  File "/tmp/ansible_dellos6_config_payload_pjEND4/ansible_dellos6_config_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/dellos6/dellos6.py", line 86, in get_config
    return _DEVICE_CONFIGS[cmd]
fatal: [sw2]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "after": null,
            "auth_pass": null,
            "authorize": true,
            "backup": true,
            "backup_options": null,
            "before": null,
            "config": null,
            "host": null,
            "lines": null,
            "match": "line",
            "parents": null,
            "password": null,
            "port": null,
            "provider": null,
            "replace": "line",
            "save": false,
            "src": null,
            "ssh_keyfile": null,
            "timeout": null,
            "update": "merge",
            "username": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "unable to retrieve current config",
    "stderr": "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 30 secs.\nSee the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide.",
    "stderr_lines": [
        "command timeout triggered, timeout value is 30 secs.",
        "See the timeout setting options in the Network Debug and Troubleshooting Guide."
    ]
```

Comment: Where in your posted code did you alter the timeout? The `invocation.module_args.timeout` is `null`, meaning it will use the default timeout value. Also, a timeout problem is usually not a "timeout problem" but rather because it is waiting for some prompt or some firewall rule is incorrect. What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far about that?

Comment: I set the persistent connect timeout to 600, just to rule out that its not actually getting interrupted while copying. As far as firewall, I can ssh fine from the machine Ansible is running on and perform tasks (I may be misunderstanding what you mean by firewall). How would I verify it's waiting for a prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to edit for anyone else experiencing this issue. It looks like it was a bug in the module that will be fixed in the latest release of Ansible.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/63272